# How to get Sql database values to MVC Razor Combo Box

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am beginner in .net MVC3 Razor. I have some queries regarding the retrieving of the values from the Sql database table fields to MVC Razor Model Page. Now consider I am using one combo box in my application in that I want to get exact table field value to the combo box I have created in the Database.

For Example:

I am using `Employee` table in my Database. Now I need to get `Employees` name from table in the Database and need to show the `Employees` name in my combo box or list box which I have created in the Model page.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438798/how-to-create-a-single-select-list-box-that-shows-the-selection-using-razor

Comment: Thanks for your Quicky Reply.But i need to retrieve the data from SQL database to the combo box.

Comment: post what have you tried

Comment: Sorry, the above link you gave has the values for the combo box was inserted in the coding part itself,But i need to Get the values from the SQL Database Table and need to show in the combo box.I cannot proceed further just created a combo Box and have no idea

Comment: What do you use to access your DB, some ORM (linqToSql, Entity framework) or just bulk SQL?

Comment: Hi i am accessing using Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

```
    public List<gridview>  getrecord(gridview record)
    {

        List<gridview> gridview1 = new List<gridview>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AGIDNET114\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Telerik;User ID=sa;Password=agiline123"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getdemotable", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
                for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    var model = new gridview();
                    model.Address = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();
                    model.Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                    model.PhoneNo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PhoneNo"].ToString();
                    model.Id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString();
                    gridview1.Add(model);
                }
            }
         return gridview1;

        }
```

follow this piece of code in model class using list you can do, then add code for your view

```
  public ActionResult getdata(gridview data)
    {
        var x = data.getrecord(data);
        return View(x);
    }
```